# Headless Server?

Tags: linux, rhel, x11, security, headless

I am running Nessus on a **closed** network. My OS is Redhat 7.4. I have Bare Metal machines in my data center and Virtual Machines on AWS.

When Nessus scans my Bare Metal machines, it correctly identifies my servers as headless and does not check for GUI banners, screen locks, etc.

On my VMs, it determines, somehow, that it is a Headed server and reports findings for GUI banners, screen locks, etc.

Any ideas what Nessus is looking at to determine if the server is headless?

Comment: I do not know about Nessus specifically, but a program could judge if a machine is headless from a number of factors (such as the presence of a running X server).

Comment: Check if there is a keyboard attached.

Comment: Agreed. I know that X server is not running. It is not even installed. Any other ideas on where it may be looking?
This one is a real stumper!

Comment: There is no keyboard, monitor or terminal attached. In fact, in AWS, there isn't even a way to attach to the console! Hashtag Sad Face

Comment: Where? I cannot find what causes Nessus to run a particular plugin. That would be most helpful. I can only find what that particular plugin is looking for, not what triggered that plugin to run.

Comment: Been there. Not what I am looking for. 
First, this site answers the question: "What is Plugin ID XXXXX scanning for?"
I need to answer the question "What does Nessus run plugin ID XXXXX"
Second, a smaller issue, I am on a closed network, which means my plugin IDs do not match those of the tenable site (so I cannot _really_ search by ID number. Need a little more work to find the equiv tenable ID#)

Comment: It about the configuration of a headless machine, not about nessus results. I'm sure there is a config file somewhere that tells Linux this is a headless machine. That is really what I am looking for,

Comment: There is no single configuration file that says a system is headless.  Nessus is doing *something* to make that determination, and you have to look at what the Nessus results say.

Comment: We had a team of three looking for two weeks regarding Nessus ID 12085 on vCenter. Even using their own forums, we never got our answer, and they never told us what they were actually checking. That's Nessus. Total PITA.

Comment: Thanks @Christopher. I can work with that answer!

Comment: Partial answer: (from the nessus .audit file I was running)
systemctl get-default | grep graphical.target
shows that the GUI can start on bootup.

Comment: Well, here's the answer. There are multiple ways to check this.
CentOS 6/7
_runlevel_
The second work is the current run level. 3 is HEADLESS, 5 is GUI.

CentOS 7
_systemctl get-default_
graphical.target is GUI mode,
multi-user.target is Headless

CentOS 6
change /etc/inittab to show 3 vice 5 to make Headless.

CentOS 7
_systemctl set-default milti-user.target_
sets headless mode or
_systemctl set-default graphical.target_

Comment: And, for completeness, NESSUS is looking for
multi-user.target AND the file /etc/gdm/custom.conf (which comes from the package gdm)

Comment: Yes. Although there is no "Answer" button ATT.